# Como crear Array Asociativo con elementos dinámicos de la pagina?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Ya vengo por el barranco con el tema, he probado de todo y me compliqué más. Necesito tomar los valores de 2 elementos de la página.
Los toma desde aquí:

```
<div class="col col-md-6 col-lg-6 text-center">
        <p><small>$ </small><small class="cuotas"><?php echo number_format($row['MontoCuota'], 2, '.', ''); ?></small></p>
    <input id="desc_men" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['Porc_Desc_Menor']; ?>" />
    <input class="cupoEleg" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['IdCupo']; ?>" />
    <input class="cantPlazas" type="hidden" value="<?php echo ($row['Cant_Mayores'] + $row['Cant_Menores']); ?>" />
</div>
```

de 2 input tipo hidden.

Hasta ahora lo hice de esta forma:

```
$(".cupoEleg").each(function(){
        totalCupoEleg.push($(this).val());
    });
$(".cantPlazas").each(function(){
        totalCupoEleg.push($(this).val());
    });
```

Lo que logré crear es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Aclaración***: (Para este ejemplo tomé dos valores, pero tal vez podrían ser uno y no creo que más de tres.)

Hasta aquí funcionaría en lo que respecta a encontrar lo valores.
Lo que necesito es tenerlo de forma clave: valor **"31"=> 3**,  **"28"=> 2** para después recorrerlo y editar el valor.
Porque según el valor que elija en un select, tendría que descontar 1 al valor guardado y cuando llegue a cero me avise.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seguramente alguien pueda orientarme o tal vez aconsejarme hacerlo de otro modo. No sé si seguir con esta idea o tal vez json sirva, pero mis conocimientos de javascript y jquery con muy básicos.
Gracias

Comment: Que elemento en tu HTML vendria a ser $(".cupoEleg"), pon una parte de tu codigo html para poder formularte una respuesta adecuada

Comment: Como los valores me los leía obvié ese código. Ya está editado. gracias.

Comment: Ok los key ya veo de donde los tares del value de los input y el value del arreglo que quieres ir formando que seria en tu $row?

Comment: No entendí bien la pregunta pero el $row me imprime los datos que traigo de una db y los muestro ahí. Luego quiero crear algo que tome esos dos datos y dinámicamente ir descontando según el value del select que se elige para saber si llega a cero. El array lo creo cuando se carga la web pero tal vez se te ocurra otra forma